# Create a Android App Service which run even after app is terminated

Tags: android, android-service

This is service which I wanted to run in the background

```
public class CustomMyService extends Service {

     public CustomMyService() {

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.ServiceStopped");
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

Manifest File

```
<service android:name=".CustomMyService">
            <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
                <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Please kindly someone let me know. I did all google and youtube search, nothing is working.

Im using redmi note 3, in which I have a option called autostart, if I give permission to this app for autostart, service runs in background.

But this option is not there in many of other android smart phone, so app services will be killed when app is terminated.

Please kindly let me know how can service be running, even after app is terminated.

Comment: Write a private class method with the code you want your service to perform and call it from `onStartCommand()`. Unless you need something to initialize the service, the constructor is not required.

Answer (score 1):

Use AlarmManager  to envoke your service time to time. Because service will be stops when app is terminated.it's need to revoke again and Alarm manage helps to start your service again.

There are many methods mention for continuous service ,but those methods are not helpful **after kitkat version**.

If you have got success to run your service continuously even after app is terminated,without use of any Alarm Manager like scheduling methods please let me know.

Comment: Alarm Manager i tried, but it did happen.. sure i ll share once i get the solution..

Answer (score 1):

See `onStartCommand` method and the param:

START_STICKY

START_NOT_STICKY

START_REDELIVER_INTENT

START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY

If doesn't work, Maybe you have no system permission to keep the service to run in the background

Comment: How does these app like Facebook, whatsapp keeps running in the background

Answer (score 0):

Here is demo :

```
 public class SyncJobService extends Service {
private String TAG = "mytag";
private Timer timer = new Timer();
private EventBus evenBus = EventBus.getDefault();
public static Date lastSyncDate;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d(TAG, "run: StartSyncEvent");
  //                Implement your logic


          }
        }, 0, 5 * 60 * 1000);//5 Minutes

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: ");
    super.onDestroy();
}

}
```

ManiFest file :

```
    <service
        android:name=".service.SyncJobService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />
```

Comment: It is for sync data with server.

Answer (score 0):

In some phones like **lenovo,xolo** etc are terminate background third party application. So , it will not allow service in background when the application is closed.Check your service with other phones.
1.Better Use Start foreground service .
2.In start sticky,if the application is terminated, service automatically restarted for background process.

Answer (score 0):

Make your service as foreground process so that the Android system will treat as foreground app and will not kill that easily. Use the below code to make your service as foreground.

```
StartForeground(100, new Notification ());
```

Remember you need to call stopforeground(100) in ondestroy of service.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution finally...

http://fabcirablog.weebly.com/blog/creating-a-never-ending-background-service-in-android